# C++ - Why is program crashing with if statement inside map iterator?

Tags: c++, if-statement, crash, iterator, maps

I am new to C++ and I am trying to iterate through the map while passing an if statement through. However the program crashes.

Please help me fix the program.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::map<int,int> h;
    std::map<int,int>::iterator it;

    h[1] = 2;
    h[4] = 5;
    for(it = h.begin(); it !=h.end(); it++){
        if (it->second > 4){
            h.erase(it->first);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're erasing element inside the for loop, and the iterator pointing to the removed element (i.e. `it`) will be invalidated. Then `it++` will cause problem.

You could

```
for (it = h.begin(); it != h.end(); ) {
    if (it->second > 4){
        it = h.erase(it);  // set it to iterator following the last removed element
    } else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your iterator removes the element the iterator is pointing to.

When an element in a `std::map` is removed, all iterators to its are immediately invalidated.

The iterator is no longer valid after the element is removed. Afterwards, the for-loop attempts to increment the no-longer-valid iterator. This is why your code crashes.

The typical solution goes something like this:

```
 for(it = h.begin(); it !=h.end(); ){
 {
    std::map<int,int>::iterator p=it;

    ++it;

    if (p->second > 4){
        h.erase(p->first);
    }
 }
```

Note, that the element is removed only after the iterator is already incremented.

Answer (score 0):

You are blowing away the iterator. It becomes invalid as soon as you remove an element from the map.

Also, you you might want to change your iterator increment to ++it. Can provide a little speed boost.